# How to filter MySQL dates?

Tags: php, mysql, date

I'm trying to do a `SELECT * FROM` but only items that are less than 30 days old. Here is my select code:

```
SELECT * FROM `{$table_name33}` WHERE `type`='wpst-requiredinfo' ORDER BY `foreignkey` ASC;
```

However, my problem is that I can't figure out how to add `WHERE AND last_updated` is less than 30 days.

I'm not exactly sure how to write the query, but the date is showing up like this: `1428412603` in the table column, it doesn't look much like a date to me. I don't know where to start.

Comment: That date is in epoch time, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this `where` clause:

```
WHERE `type`='wpst-requiredinfo' and
      last_updated >= date_sub(now(), interval 30 day)
```

EDIT:

Your date seems to be in Unix time format.

```
WHERE `type`='wpst-requiredinfo' and
      last_updated >= unixtime_timestamp() - 30*24*60*60
```

Note:  this puts all the functions on the current time.  In particular, it does not use `FROM_UNIXTIME(last_updated)`.  This ensures that an index can be used for this part of the query.  The best index would be on `(type, last_updated)`.

Comment: thanks for the speedy reply. i copy+pasted that... it didnt break anything, nor did it change anything. i flipped around > and < and tried 1 day instead of 30 just to be sure, but nothing changed. :-/

Comment: My entire answer only applies to the `where` clause.  If you are happy with the unix time, then put that in the `select`.  If you want a datetime value, then use `from_unixtime()`.

Comment: ok trying this... newb question, does last_updated need ticks around it since its a column name? as well, as im reading it, it says where last_updated is greater than or equal to 30 days old.. correct?

Comment: @GeoffHill . . . You only need backticks when an indentifier (column or table name) uses a reserved word or has unusual characters (spaces, periods, etc.).  If you use good naming conventions, then backticks are not necessary and only serve to make queries harder to read, harder to write, and less portable to different databases.  So, you do not need them for `last_updated`.

Comment: Thank you
I tried:
`last_updated >= date_sub(unixtime_timestamp(now()), interval 30 day)`

And now no records are showing.. but the records were last_updated within 30 days... :-/

Comment: unfortunately it returns 0 results. Here is the entire line without the new code:

`"SELECT * FROM `{$table_name}` WHERE `user_id`={$wpscst_userid} AND `email`='{$wpscst_email}' ORDER BY `last_updated` DESC;";`

Comment: @GordonLindoff, date_sub expects a date, not an (epoch) integer, as its first argument.  I think you want `unix_timestamp(date_sub(now(), interval ...))`

Comment: @pilcrow . . . I think I was confused when I wrote that.  I just removed that version.  The last version, using `- 30*24*60*60` should work.

Comment: @GordonLinoff unfortunately, still returning 0 results... im not sure why :-/ i tried with now() and without on your last edit... im at a loss, really

Comment: @GordonLinoff my line looks like SELECT * FROM `{$table_name}` WHERE `user_id`={$wpscst_userid} AND `email`='{$wpscst_email}' AND last_updated <= unixtime_timestamp(now()) - 30*24*60*60 ORDER BY `last_updated` DESC;  (((i tried without now() too)))

Comment: @GordonLinoff does it matter to know im not actually echoing the date? (what i mean is, im simply using this to hide any record that is older than 30 days) also, perhaps it might be better to use an IF statement within my php insead of in the mysql query. I can just if date more than 30 days style="display:none;" ... i know its barbaric but it may work, right?

Comment: Im going to mark this as answered because i believe im the only one doing something wrong here... i appreciate the responses. ill see what i can do :)

Comment: @GeoffHill You shouldn't accept it, since you asked the same again http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29581256/in-php-my-last-updated-is-unix-date-how-would-i-add-a-conditional-statement